# Trigger a multibranch pipeline job by the PR for a specified branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Now I have a multibranch pipeline and configured to be triggered by PR create.
I just want the job be triggered when I make a PR to branch develop, but now any PR to any branch will trigger this job.
I install the SCM API plugin and configured the Filter by name (with regular expression) as "develop", but not working.
Any one can give some suggestions?
PS:
I'm using bitbucket to store code

Comment: This plugin seem works: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Branch+PR+Filter+Plugin